# Passing a url from one php file to another

Tags: php

I have a search function, that searches for youtube videos and display them on my front page. Just like YouTube I want to have another page on my site, so that when they click on a video, it takes them to a new page and display the video there - still part of my website.

I have a search.php where you can make the search and a video.php where you should be able to watch a video.

I had this on my video.php:

```
    <a href='video.php?var=$video_id['v']'>Data link</a>
```

$video_id['v'] = contains the url of the youtube page.

and on my video.php I have:

```
    <?php
      echo $_GET['var'];
    ?>
```

the value of var is equal to "var". not the URL I was suppose to get.  do you know what should I do?

Comment: use `urlencode()` on `$video_id['v']`

Comment: enclose `$video_id['v']` in PHP tags and echo it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$url = sprintf('video.php?var=%s', $video_id['v']);
<a href="<?php echo $url; ?>">Data link</a>
```

Comment: But this doesn't fix the OP's problem, does it?

Answer (score 3):

In your search.php

```
echo "<a href='video.php?var=".urlencode($video_id['v'])."'>Data link</a>";
```

This will allow you to add a full url (including other & and ?) as a variable to an url.

Comment: What exactly is not working. What are you seeing in the HTML?

Comment: When you click the link and are watching video.php, what is the url in the browser? Perhaps `$video_id['v']` has no value to begin with.

Comment: it has a value, it actually holds the ids of the videos in youtube. for every video the id is different.

Comment: can you do a `var_dump($video_id);` just before your link and update your question with the output?

Answer (score 1):

The page you have `$video_id['v']`, that means search.php, please inspect it first to know if its getting desired value before checking at video.php

How would you do that:
Just before that Anchor tag, `print_r($video_id['v'])`, [print_r](http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php) is a debug function in PHP

Now I am keeping the style you have with the required correction. You have done some mistakes. I am explaining below.

```
    <a href="video.php?var=<?php echo urlencode($video_id['v'])?>">Data link</a>
```

1. HTML attributes, ie href should be provided values in double quotes not single ones.
2. You didn't keep the enclosure of the quote marks. Two single quotes collide with each other and it breaks.
3. Inside pure HTML you used variable for PHP which will not be parsed.
4. Even if you had PHP in there you used single quote which wont parse variables inside.
5. URLs need to be encoded to pass through URL (ie $_GET).